# Symfony2 using second database while testing

Tags: mysql, symfony, behat

Im using behat for testing in my symfony2 aplication. Right now I need to have two databases. First (which is working right now), for normal use, like user doing something on site. Second database (which exists and behat work on it), for tests purpose.

What I got now is two working databases, and behat. Behat use second database, but problem is that while tests flow, site doesnt use it.

My `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

My `config_test.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname:   "%database_name%_test"
```

My 'behat.yml':

```
default:
suites:
    default:
        paths:
            features: '%paths.base%/features'
            bootstrap:  '%paths.base%/features/bootstrap'
        contexts:
            - FeatureContext: ~
            - EwidencjaContext:
                userManager: '@fos_user.user_manager'
                em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
                packageManager: '@em.package_manager'
extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url:  http://my_nginx/app_test.php
        goutte: ~
        selenium2:
            browser: "chrome"
            wd_host: http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub
            capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome"}
    Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
        image_drivers:
            local:
                screenshot_directory: tests/features/images/
                clear_screenshot_directory: true
```

What can I do to change database for time tests are in progress?

Comment: What do you mean with site doesn't use it? Is that while executing functional tests or when browsing to the site to test

Comment: It doesnt use test database on the site.

Comment: To use it on your site you should make sure the kernel uses the test environment. Just like the dev environment is used in app_dev.php

Comment: I had no `app_test.php` file at all, I created one, copied everything from `app_dev.php`, and changed just one line for `$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);`. It still doesnt work, and when i go on http://localhost/app_test.php it just download the file, not like when I go on http://localhost/app_dev.php, when i got on site in dev invironment.

Comment: Check your webserver configuration http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Show me you behat.yml please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses SQLite for Behat (test) environment but you can use MySQL if you want to.

**config_test.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_sqlite
                path: %kernel.cache_dir%/default.db
                charset: UTF8
```

**app_test.php**

The relevant line should be: `$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);`

**AppKernel.php**

The relevant line should be: `if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'])) {`

**behat.yml**

Pay attention to `app_test.php`.

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://your_app_domain.dev/app_test.php
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

**Virtual hosts settings:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName your_app_domain.dev
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/app/web"

   <Directory "/path/to/your/app/web">
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/your_app_domain.dev.error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/your_app_domain.dev.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Some information:**

- [Setting up isolated environments as a symfony application base](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/cz5k/setting-up-isolated-environments-as-a-symfony-application-base)
- [Behat blog posts](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat)

**Outcome:**

If you call `http://your_app_domain.dev/app_dev.php` it will use default DB settings in config but if you call `http://your_app_domain.dev/app_test.php` then it will use config_test settings.

Comment: Along with it I had to change one line in `vhost.conf` to `location ~ ^/(app_dev|app|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {` couse it was lacking an `app_test` part. Now everything works good, thanks. And im using mysql. Now that i read about it, seems like sqlite would be better choice. Im going to see how to set it up, thanks for help.

Comment: @Megami Just a note, I see you are dependency injecting services to EwidencjaContext. In the case of behat, your context should implement `KernelAwareContext` and access services&parameters from `$container`. An example is here: [Installing behat3 with composer.json](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/v2zi/installing-behat3-with-composer-json). This way you don't need to inject anything to your context files from behat.yml and keep behat.yml as clean as possible.